# Database Connectivity with open layer 3 and postgresql

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver, postgresql-9.5

I trying to make website of map ,but i new to these technology so i completed little bit code in html and i installed Geo-server,PostgreSQL,but i don't know how to connect the server to the html code ,I seen video but don't get properly so please anyone help me how i connect to server,and also suggest me which is better for connectivity and coding  means leaflet,open layer or.net MVC.I want to do mapping of 30 cities from India so i want to display only India

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>hello</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\asset\ol4\css\ol.css" type="text/css">
  
   <script src="../asset/ol4/js/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
      a.skiplink {
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        height: px;
        width: px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      a.skiplink:focus {
        clip: auto;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0.3em;
      }
      #map:focus {
        outline: #4A74A8 solid 0.15em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="skiplink" href="#map">Go to map</a>
    <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0"></div>
    <button id="zoom-out">Zoom out</button>
    <button id="zoom-in">Zoom in</button>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
          })
        }),
        view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      document.getElementById('zoom-out').onclick = function() {
        var view = map.getView();
        var zoom = view.getZoom();
        view.setZoom(zoom - 1);
      };

      document.getElementById('zoom-in').onclick = function() {
        var view = map.getView();
        var zoom = view.getZoom();
        view.setZoom(zoom + 1);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

map and how i disable the other part of map in open layer or leaflet. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good set of [OpenLayers examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/) - the one you want is the [WMS example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-tiled.html).

You need to create a layer that loads from GeoServer:

```
var layers = [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states', 'TILED': true},
        serverType: 'geoserver'
      })
    })
  ];
```

Comment: Thanks sir for giving this answer but still my code is not working,i don't understand the URL,i created layer from geo-server and this is URL "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Seema/wms"  for the layer and what is the extent ,if i want to display India country map then how  to add the extent value in it...I modified old code .so

Comment: what doesn't work? what does the network tab show? what does the GeoServer log show?

Comment: The geo-server layer is display but after adding the layer path in html code then browser is only showing the zoom-in and zoom-out buttons. map cant  display.thanks

Comment: tahnks sir for help.